# Integer becomes Long when passed to the method that is expecting a Object Type

Tags: java, object, integer, autoboxing

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        process(true ? 1 : 2L);
    }


    static void process(Object object)
    {
        System.out.println(object instanceof Integer);
    }
}
```

> My expected output is **true**.
>
> But actual out put is **false**.

My understanding is between integral data types the largest type will be assigned. 
If so what is this called?

Comment: Err, why would you expect that the "larger" type of 1 Integer and 2L Long ... would be Integer?

Comment: By the way... please type always `L` instead of `l`. Regarding the font, it can be easily misread as `1` (the number) .

Answer (score 1):

The then and else parts of `true ? 1 : 2l` are `int` and `long`. The result is the widest, `long`, the the then-part is cast to long. See [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25).

In Computer Science a term for this is *balancing types*.

```
34 / 2.0        // double, more a case of _widening a type_.
c ? 2.0 : 34    // double
```

Comment: In particular this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2

Comment: @ACV a jewe worth reading. Unfortunately the ternary conversions are not listed _there_.

Answer (score 0):

Like stated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25), a ternary expression with `int` and `long` will be subjected to [binary numeric conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), resulting in a `long`.